# How to add text into a plot in pyqtgraph like matplotlib.plot.text()

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Like the title said, I want to add a text into a graph which I used pyqtgraph to plot, but I didn't find any function like matplotlib.plot.text() which I could set the text and even position in the graph.

```
        self.plt_1.setLabel('left', 'CDF')
        self.plt_1.setLabel('bottom', 'Delay', units='ms')
        self.plt_1.setXRange(0, 200)
        self.plt_1.setYRange(0, 1)
        self.plt_1.setWindowTitle('DL CDF Curve')
        self.plt_1.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)
        self.plt_1.setMenuEnabled(False)
        self.plt_1.setText(30, 20, str(self.x_dl_5g_flag))
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work in my case,  does anyone know how to do it in pyqtgraph? thanks

Answer (score 3):

```py
self.text = pg.TextItem(str(self.x_dl_5g_flag))
self.plt_1.addItem(self.text)
self.text.setPos(30,20)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add text to a graph and define its position on the plot in coordinates relative to the plot canvas (not data coordinates) you can use `LabelItem` instead of `TextItem`, something along the following lines (with `pyqtgraph` imported as `pg`):

```py
self.text_label = pg.LabelItem("Your text")
self.text_label.setParentItem(self.plt_1.graphicsItem())
self.text_label.anchor(itemPos=(0.4, 0.1), parentPos=(0.4, 0.1))
```